# Is there a way to take the source of an html5 video as an input by the user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

Say I have a video element in my html page without the source specified

```
<video controls>
<source src="">
</video>
```

and an empty input element

```
<input></input>
```

I want the user to paste the source of the video he wants to see in the input element and press enter to see it. But I simply can't figure out even what to google/learn in order to be able to do it. Can anyone help? Here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/aj9jy6tv/

So, just to clarify, what I want a text field where the user can enter a url location to a video source, then when they press enter, the application grabs that text and populates the source of the video tag with it

Comment: a url? a file? what source?

Comment: url for the src attribute of the source tag what else

Comment: i mean you say the user to paste it in. where does that come from?

Comment: that is basically the user problem something like http://www.blahblah/blahblah.mp4

Comment: is it on disk or is it a url to a web server?

Comment: anywhere on the internet like https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4

Comment: So, just to clarify, you basically want a text field where the user can enter a url location to a video source, then when they click "update" or whatever, the application grabs that text and populates the source of the video tag with it?

Comment: yes exactly thank you

Comment: @Fazy do u know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will grab the value from the input and change the `src` attribute. You must then call `load()` and `play()`. You can mess with how you want to do the input to get it the way you want.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9yebvvc2/) here showing functionality.

```js
// Note this is the url im pasting into the input: https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg

(function() {
  document.getElementById('url').addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
      var url = this.value;
      document.getElementById("video_res_1").src = url;
      document.getElementById("video1").load();
      document.getElementById("video1").play(); 
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<input type="text" id="url" placeholder="Enter Url">
<video id="video1" width="240" height="160">
    <source id="video_res_1" src="" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

Comment: I clicked load and nothing happened. and I need to press enter not click on a button

Comment: @UsmanSikander I updated the code to grab input on enter press. Also you have to put a valid url into the input box.

Comment: u r right sorry but it still didnt work I used the url https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg. I am proably doing someting wrong could u share a jsfiddle

Comment: when I try to run code snippit it give all these error messages and on jsfiddle website it just does'nt work.

Comment: @UsmanSikander I updated the answer and included a fiddle should work now

Comment: finally worked thank u so much for your unconditional effort and time